# How can I stretch an image used in a figure in one (e.g. vertical) direction, say in an \includegraphics command?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

A circle in the particular image in this case is "squashed" in the vertical direction. The image includes a big circle that gets displayed as an ellipse compressed in the vertical direction, so that it's a "horizontal major axis ellipse." I want to stretch this to make it appear as a circle.

Two different \includegraphics commands I've used.

\includegraphics[width=5.5in] {ViewFromN.png}
\includegraphics[width=5.5in,keepaspectratio=TRUE] {ViewFromN.png} % result is the same as above

Comment: what happens if you use no optional argument at all, are you sure it is round to start with?  the forms you show are equivalent and should scale equally in both directions.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that it wasn't round to start with; though I thought it was---that's why I added "keepaspectratio." Once I fixed the problem at the source of the image, I didn't have the problem anymore. Though I'm still interested in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With `\vstretch` from the `scalerel` package.  Of course, you need to specify the stretch ratio.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}
\vstretch{1.1}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}}
\vstretch{.8}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried your example of using scalerel but I ran into a problem – Byron Dom 2 days ago   
[[ From console output: ]] Unfortunately, the package scalerel could not be installed.Please check the log file: C:/Users/byron/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log

Comment: LAST ENTRY IN pdflatex.log: 2021-02-02 14:07:37,459-0800 INFO pdflatex - installing package scalerel triggered by tex\latex\scalerel\scalerel.sty 2021-02-02 14:07:37,664-0800 FATAL pdflatex - No Data 2021-02-02 14:07:37,664-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Info: ="get host by name failed in tcp_connect()" 2021-02-02 14:07:37,664-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp 2021-02-02 14:07:37,664-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1119

Comment: @ByronDom That error indicates your machine was not able to get the package from its server.  I would only say that the package is not new and has been around a number of years.  If you can't resolve your TeX installation to fix this, you can always download the style file and PDF manual from here: https://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel.  If the sty file is in the same directory as your source file, it should use it.  However, you really need to figure out why your installation couldn't install it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the image actually contains an ellipse that was supposed to be a circle. (Maybe update the question to provide the image.) The answer will depend on making measurements from the output to determine how much stretching is needed to restore the circle.

```
\includegraphics[width=5.5in,height=5.9???in,keepaspectratio=FALSE]{ViewFromN.png}
```

where you will have to determine the height. Note that `keepaspectratio=FALSE`is the default, but it is explicit here for clarity. It only affectes the result when both width and height are specified.

Another answer is

```
\scalebox{1}[1.25???]{\includegraphics[width=5.5in]{ViewFromN.png}}
```

which separates the scaling from the width specification. Again, the vertical scale factor will be up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the comments.